# Is there a map accumulate for things that aren't foldable?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Let's say I have a binary tree:

```hs
data BinTree a
  = Nil
  | Branch a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
```

I'd like to do an accumulate map on a structure like this:

```hs
mapAccum ::
  (
  )
    => (a -> b -> (c, a)) -> a -> BinTree b -> BinTree c
mapAccum func x Nil =
  Nil
mapAccum func x (Branch y left right) =
  let
    (y', x') =
      func x y
  in
    Branch y' (mapAccum func x' left) (mapAccum func x' right)
```

Which performs a map with an accumulator across the structure.

However this is a very general pattern.  We can do this on all sorts of tree like structures, and if there's a nice, common-place abstraction I'd prefer to use that over rolling my own here.

There's a function on `Traversable`s:

```hs
mapAccumL :: Traversable t => (s -> a -> (s, b)) -> s -> t a -> (s, t b)
```

Which sort of does the same thing on lists.  But it requires `Foldable` in a way that means it wouldn't work on binary trees.  What I'm looking for would be a more basic version of this which works without `Foldable`.

I can make it work on types made with `Cofree`:

```hs
mapAccum ::
  ( Functor f
  )
    => (a -> b -> (c, a)) -> a -> Cofree f b -> Cofree f c
mapAccum func x (y :< rest) =
  let
    (y', x') =
      func x y
  in
    y' :< fmap (mapAccum func x') rest
```

Which shows that it's at least generally applicable to tree-like structures.

Is there a common abstraction for this function?

Comment: I suspect `recursion-schemes` has the sort of generalization you're after. It's not very well documented for the most part, but `cata` is probably sufficient for your needs and that's straightforward.

Comment: I'm confused by "it requires Foldable in a way that means it wouldn't work on binary trees." In what way does `Foldable` not work for your binary tree? I could see `Functor` not working, if you have an unstated requirement that it be a binary *search* tree. But `Foldable` works fine on a binary search tree.

Comment: @Carl, note that the same `x'` goes to each child. This is a tree-like fold, not a list-like fold.

Comment: It's not that you can't write a foldable instance, but rather that any instance would need to traverse the structure in a linear order, and thus the `mapAccumL` that is built from this instance would give the wrong result.

Comment: I rewrote it to this so far: `mapAccum func = flip go where go Nil = const Nil; go (Branch y left right) = \x -> let (y', x') = func x y in (Branch y' <$> go left <*> go right) x'` I feel like the right generalization will pop more readily out of that form.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data BinTree a
  = Nil
  | Branch a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
  deriving (Functor)

makeBaseFunctor ''BinTree
```

The Template Haskell splice will define

```
data BinTreeF a x
  = NilF
  | BranchF a x x
  deriving (Functor)
```

as well as instances of the `Base` type family and the `Recursive` and `Corecursive` classes for `BinTree`. Thanks to that `Recursive` instance, you can use

```
cata :: Recursive t => (Base t r -> r) -> t -> r
```

at the type

```
cata :: (BinTreeF b (BinTree c) -> BinTree c) -> BinTree b -> BinTree c
```

Specifically,

```
mapAccum:: a -> b -> (c, a)) -> a -> BinTree b -> BinTree c
mapAccum func = \x t -> cata go t x
  where
    go NilF _x = Nil
    go (BranchF y leftres rightres) x =
      let
        (y', x') = func x y
      in
        Branch y' (leftres x') (rightres x')
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
transverse :: (Recursive s, Corecursive t, Functor f) 
           => (forall r. Base s (f r) -> f (Base t r)) 
           -> s -> f t
```

at the type

```
transverse :: (forall r. BinTreeF b (a -> r) -> a -> BinTreeF c r) 
           -> BinTree b -> a -> BinTree c
```

like so

```
mapAccum:: forall a b c. (a -> b -> (c, a)) -> a -> BinTree b -> BinTree c
mapAccum func = \x t -> transverse go t x
  where
    go :: BinTreeF b (a -> r) -> a -> BinTreeF c r
    go NilF _x = NilF
    go (BranchF y leftres rightres) x =
      let
        (y', x') = func x y
      in
        BranchF y' (leftres x') (rightres x')
```

Comment: I think this might miss the point. It sounded to me like the asker wanted a function that could work on more types than just `BinTree`, like how `mapAccumL` works on any `Traversable` rather than just `[]`. This uses general things in the implementation of the function, but the final product is still specific to `BinTree`.

Comment: They asked if there was a way to use a “nice, commonplace abstraction”. `Data.Functor.Foldable` provides that abstraction, and this answer shows how to use it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, in some cases, you can do things with, e.g., the `Bifunctor` instance of the base functor. In this case, I don't see anything super-obvious, because a particular field of each node needs to have an effect (`local`, basically) in the children. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Ah, `Bifunctor` was exactly the clue I needed to come up with something (though I ended up needing the power of `Bitraversable`). It's slightly insane, but the important thing is that it works!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalization of what you wrote, using the `bifunctors` and `recursion-schemes` packages:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy
import Data.Bifunctor.TH
import Data.Bitraversable
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

data BinTree a = Nil | Branch a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
makeBaseFunctor ''BinTree
deriveBifunctor ''BinTreeF
deriveBifoldable ''BinTreeF
deriveBitraversable ''BinTreeF

mapAccum :: (Base tc ~ f c, Base tb ~ f b, Bitraversable f, Recursive tb,
  Corecursive tc) => (a -> b -> (c, a)) -> a -> tb -> tc
mapAccum func x ys = embed ys' where
  (ys', x') = runState (bitraverse (state . flip func) (pure . mapAccum func x') (project ys)) x

-- a slightly less general version, but that's usually good enough,
-- and will fix most ambiguous type errors
mapAccum' :: (Base (t c) ~ f c, Base (t b) ~ f b, Bitraversable f, Recursive (t b),
  Corecursive (t c)) => (a -> b -> (c, a)) -> a -> t b -> t c
mapAccum' = mapAccum
```

The way it works is that it traverses over all of the values in the current element of the tree (for your tree in particular, this is always just one element), transforming them and coming up with a new accumulator value, then recursively calling itself on each subelement of the tree with that value. Also, since it's lazy state, it ties the knot so it only has to walk the structure once instead of twice. In other words, note that `x'` comes from the output of `runState`, but it's passed as part of the parameters to it. In a strict language, this would result in an infinite loop, but since Haskell is lazy, `x'` isn't evaluated until it's needed, at which point the part of the code that generated it is finished.

Comment: I thought about `bitraverse`, but didn't get quite there. Is it possible to use that under `transverse`? If not, I imagine you could at *least* use `cata`. `embed` with `project` is a bit low-level.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think it's possible to use `cata`, since that would need an algebra specific to the type, which I don't have one of, and don't think I can get. I might be able to use `transverse`; I'll give it a try.

Comment: @dfeuer Especially after the knot-tying trick I just added, I don't see a way to use `transverse` either. I'm not confident that there is no way; I just can't find one.

Comment: I do not understand this knot-tying trick. Maybe you could add a bit of explanation?

Comment: @dfeuer How's that sound?

Comment: So you're doing it to accumulate the state changes within the node in the same traversal as descending the children? It seems more natural to think of that first stuff as a fold in the first type argument and the second stuff as a traversal (in `Reader`) in the second (or maybe it's even just `bimap`????). It's unfortunate that `Bifoldable` doesn't include a `firstFoldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> p a x -> m` method; that would presumably take care of your efficiency concerns. (I haven't worked out any of the details, so please forgive my wild hand waving.)

Comment: @dfeuer The first stuff really does need to be a traversal, since it needs to both update the structure and return the new accumulator. The second stuff is effectively just a plain `fmap`. So I don't think `firstFoldMap` would be helpful. Now if `Bitraversable` included a `firstTraverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f c) -> p a b -> f (p c b)`, I could use that along with an `fmap` after, but I feel like that would still give up the performance advantage from tying the knot.

Comment: Hrm? Can't you use `Bifoldable` to calculate the new accumulator and `bimap` to use it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dfeuer Wouldn't that mean I'd definitely have to walk the whole thing twice, calling `func :: (a -> b -> (c, a))` on each element both times, and only consuming half of the result each time?

Comment: I wonder if you could use something like [the `Ap (Mono x y)` applicative](https://elvishjerricco.github.io/2017/03/23/applicative-sorting.html) to capture all the results as well as the final state. I don't know how it'll compare to the knot tying for performance.